# Github Actions not Sharing Cache Between Pipelines

Tags: docker, github-actions

I'm currently trying to replicate a Gitlab setup on Github Actions. I'm fairly new to Actions. For the most part my configuration is working and is currently using cache (not artefacts, which I will get to at some point, once I'm happy with just cache). The pipeline itself contains a Svelte application which is built and tested within my `build_and_test` job before being dockerised.

My `main.yml` contains the initial configuration where `build_and_test` is run and a test docker run is performed to ensure the image can be built. These should run on all push events to development branches and main. So far so good. I am caching artefacts such as `node_modules` and `.npm` `build_and_test` and fetching these using the same key in `validate_docker_build`.

The problem I have is when I come to my `deployment.yml`. The steps in this file are almost identical to those in `validate_docker_build`, except that `docker save` is run. A final deployment step will run, but for now just echos text to the terminal.

The `build_and_save_docker_image` job within `deployment.yml` currently cannot access the cache used within `main.yml`, even though the key is the same.`deployment.yml` runs only during pull requests at the moment. I have check the Github UI and the cache exists. The first screenshot below shows that the cache hit is occurring.

[image]

The second screenshot shows that the cache has been created.

[image]

The final screenshot shows a cache miss in the final job resulting in an error in the Docker build because `node_modules` is not present.

[image]

```
Dockerfile:59
--------------------
  57 |     COPY --from=builder /app/express-server.js .
  58 |     COPY --from=builder /app/src/lib/blogs ./src/lib/blogs
  59 | >>> COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
  60 |     
  61 |     EXPOSE 5000
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 311477b8-1c34-4c55-965f-f41b7f0bb28c::kgekgkod5dmq3mjy8qhpc0tyt: "/app/node_modules": not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

What am I missing to be able to access the cache in this last stage?

`main.yml`

```
name: Build and test Janus frontend

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'JWEB-*'
      - 'release-*'
      - main


env:
  cache-name: cache-node-modules

jobs:
  build_and_test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '20'

      - name: Cache .npm and node_modules
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: |
            app/.npm
            app/node_modules
            app/yarn.lock
            app/build
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('app/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}
            ${{ runner.os }}-build-
            ${{ runner.os }}-

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          cd app
          yarn install --cache-folder .npm --prefer-offline
          yarn install --frozen-lockfile

      - name: Run build
        run: |
          cd app
          yarn build

      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          cd app
          yarn test


  validate_docker_build:
    needs: build_and_test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Get build cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: |
            app/.npm
            app/node_modules
            app/yarn.lock
            app/build
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('app/yarn.lock') }}
      - name: Build docker image
        run: |
          docker build -f app/Dockerfile -t janus_ui:${{github.sha}} --target production app/
```

`deployment.yml`

```
name: Deployment

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - 'release-*'

env:
  cache-name: cache-node-modules

jobs:
  build_and_save_docker_image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Get build cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: |
            app/.npm
            app/node_modules
            app/yarn.lock
            app/build
            .docker
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('app/yarn.lock') }}
      - name: Build docker image
        run: |
          mkdir -p .docker
          ls app/
          docker build -f app/Dockerfile -t janus_ui:${{github.sha}} --target production app/
          docker save --output .docker/janus_ui-${{github.sha}}.tar janus_ui:${{github.sha}}

  deploy_image:
    needs: build_and_save_docker_image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Get build cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: .docker
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('app/yarn.lock') }}
      - name: Build docker image
        run: |
          echo 'This will deploy here'
```